# Where can I find Codesmith templates?

Tags: wpf, winforms, codesmith

I am new to Codesmith. Are there any templates for Windows Forms and WPF?
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[template share forum.](http://community.codesmithtools.com/File_Share/f/7.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The .netTiers templates will generate strongly typed winforms controls. They ship with CodeSmith and are located in the Template Explorer. If you are looking for a set of templates that generate complete forms than this is something we don't have out of the box, but you could always build a template for this. On our [community site](http://community.codesmithtools.com/) there is a set of [Silverlight UI + validation templates](http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/external/archive/2010/07/29/codesmith-xaml-templates-171-oscar-agreda-s-blog.aspx) that may interest you.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski